# Unable to use Samba with SMBv2 or 3

Tags: samba, windows-10, smb

Is there a way to make Linux shares appear in Networks (Win10-Home and Prof) other than using SMBv1 ?

I am running 20.04 with Samba 4.11.6 and I am unable to reach my Linux shares from Windows 10 via Networks when using SMBv2 or 3.
I can reach my shares via mapping \name\share or when SMBv1 is enabled on Windows with no issues.

I do not want to use SMBv1 or use the \name\share method.

I unchecked all SMBv1 boxes in Windows and tried various below combinations in my smb.conf file but SMB2 or 3 doesnt work.

client min protocol = SMB2

client max protocol = SMB3

min protocol = SMB2

max protocol = SMB3

protocol = SMB2

protocol = SMB3

server min protocol = SMB2

server max protocol = SMB3

I also shut down all firewalls (Win/Linux) for troubleshooting and tried different registry hacks but so far the only way to make it work is to use the insecure SMBv1.
Is there anything that I need to enable on either Win or Linux ?

Comment: Just noting that I have the SMBv1 enabled on my Windows 10 for only seeing the network.  When I connect to my Samba shares it connects at SMB 3.11 by default.  You can always check your connections on your Samba server by running `sudo smbstatus`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to have Win10 "discover" shares by NetBIOS name because that requires SMB1.

You can connect to the server with a \linux-host-name.local if you want.

Or you could configure WS-Discovery on the Linux server:

I submitted this as a bug / feature request in launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1831441

There exists in github something that has most of this already created. One can use it in Ubuntu but it requires some work to implement:

[1] Download the file:

```
wget https://github.com/christgau/wsdd/archive/master.zip
```

[2] UnZip it:

```
unzip master.zip
```

[3] Rename the python script

```
sudo mv wsdd-master/src/wsdd.py wsdd-master/src/wsdd
```

[4] Copy it to /usr/bin

```
sudo cp wsdd-master/src/wsdd /usr/bin
```

[5] A systemd service file is already provided in the package it just needs to be copied to the correct location:

```
sudo cp wsdd-master/etc/systemd/wsdd.service /etc/systemd/system
```

[6] The wsdd.service file ( /etc/systemd/system/wsdd.service ) has to be edited to remove references to the nobody user:

```
#User=nobody
#Group=nobody
```

[7] Then enable the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start wsdd
sudo systemctl enable wsdd
```

Now Win10 can discover the Ubuntu server with its own native WSD protocol and there is no need to enable smb1.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will be taking the wsdd route. I tested it and it works fine. Thanks again.